# How to update table field value in one table from field value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update field value from one table to another.

Item with bomRev='A' in Destination table look like show below
[image]

Same Item bomRev='A' in source table looks like

[image]

I want to update `partid` field in destination table for `bomRev=A` by the value in Source filed i want to destination looks exactly like the source.

I tried this but no luck

```
 UPDATE [MIBOMD] 
       SET [MIBOMD].[partId] = [assy].[partId] 
       FROM [MIBOMD]  INNER JOIN  [assy] ON [MIBOMD].[partId] = [assy].[partId] 
       WHERE bomRev='A'  and [bomItem]='600797' AND [MIBOMD].[partId]!=[assy].[partId];
```

Comment: *I tried this but no luck*... what does that mean? Did you get an error? Did it run, but updated the wrong data? Be more specific.

Comment: @sstan It show me one row affected message but record is not chnaged

Comment: Question is not clear. You want to update partiId But you have multiple partid with same bomItem Make me clear please

Comment: @NeerPriv Yes i have the same field in two tables there is `partId` field in `[MIBOMD]` also in `assy` tables. i want to update/ make partid field in `[MIBOMD]` to be identical to `assy`. This two tables contains BOM or Bill of Material or component of an Assembled item when there is BOM  change in assy table `[MIBOMD]` has to be updated

Comment: you could not. Because bomItem has multiple partid Which partid you want?

Comment: `bomitem + bom Entry` in `[MIBOMD]` table and  `itemID+ bom Entry` in `[assy]' table are unique

Comment: Easy then just add that as another condition of the join.  see below I already made the edit

Comment: @Matt you mean the second Bom?

Comment: BomEntry I deleted my other comment about precedence because you have given use the unique keys to join between tables so now you have a 1 to 1 relationship and the update is not problematic.  Test out the code and see below for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE m
    SET [partId] = a.[partId] 
FROM
    [MIBOMD] m
    INNER JOIN 
    [assy] a
    ON m.[bomItem] = a.[ItemId]
AND m.bomEntry = a.bomEntry
WHERE
    m.bomRev='A'
    AND m.[bomItem]='600797'
    AND m.[partId]!=a.[partId];
```

You actually were pretty close!  Just a couple of key differences. Before I explain I have used Table Aliases in the code I provided it is a shorthand way of referring to the table throughout the query that will make it a little easier to follow and read.  To Alias a table after the table name in the from statement simply add a space and an alias or a space " AS " alias.

Now your Join as on `partid` in your version and that was your main issue.  Because you want the records where `partid` are not the same so you can change the `partid` of the `assy` table.  Looking at your dataset I was able to determine that the shared key was `mibomd.bomItem` and `assy.ItemId`.  After clearing that up everything should be good.

Per your comment the only other thing that needed to be added was a second condition on the join to make it unique.  `[MIBOMD].bomEntry = assy.bomEntry`

A little about join conditions.  Typically you always want to figure out what the unique relationship between the 2 tables are (`bomItem` = `ItemId` and `bomEntry = bomEntry`) and that is what will go in the ON area of the join.  Rarely that will be different and will be for very specific purposes.

Per your comment on how to insert the missing records

```
INSERT INTO MIBOMD (bomItem, bomRev, bomEntry, lineNbr, dType, partId)
SELECT
    bomItem = a.ItemId
    ,bomRev = 'A'  --or change the value to what you want
    ,a.bomEntry
    ,lineNbr = ???? --not sure how you are figure this out do if you wan it to be the next line number you can figure that out automatically if you need
    ,a.partId
FROM
    assy a
    LEFT JOIN MIBOMD m
    ON a.ItemId = m.bomItem
    AND a.bomEntry = m.bomEntry
WHERE
    m.bomItem IS NULL
```

This time you would use a `left join` from `assy` to `mibomd` and figure out when they don't match `mibomd.bomItem IS NULL`

Comment: works great but how can i add the second bom? or partid=201881?

Comment: If you want to update everything that is not equal take out the AND m.bomItem = '600797' condition from the where statement.  That will update anything in the table that is not the same.  Just to confirm though you are updating Mibomd with assay value that is what you want right?

Comment: Also do you only want to update  m.bomRev='A' or any bomRev?  if you want all Revs take out that line in the where condition too

Comment: If you go with the solution please accept my answer as the solution for you.

Comment: What i am trying say is in `[MIBOMD]` table there are two partid value whereas on the `assy` table there are three. how can i add the remaining partid. the update works great but it doesnt add

Comment: It should have updated both. Because both are Rev = 1 and bomItem 600797 and both have partids that are different from assy and both will match the unique keys provided.  When you ran the query did it tell you how may records where updated in the results window?  Run a query on MIBOMD and see if it worked for you.

Comment: it telling me two row affected but i am looking to see three row to be affected, the  two row update, which is perfect, also want 1 partid = 201881 need to be added. I am talking just Rev A only . if you see the pictures in my question the first one has three parts of rev A but the other one has only two after the update it should show three Thanks!!

Comment: I updated the answer with an insert statement you can modify.